# Simple Form diferente input para um model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery-masked-input

Tenho no meu database uma coluna `value` com *precision 7* e 2 tipo big decimal.
No meu form uso o simple form e também uso o Mask, ou seja campo para entrada de valor ficaria mais ou menos assim:

70.567,54

Porém, na hora de salvar, o controller recebe isto como string e automaticamente converte, e tudo o que há depois do primeiro ponto se perde ficando somente
70.0.

Eu tentei usar o `gsub` retirar os "." e converter a "," para ponto e deixar que ele se virasse em converter para big decimal, mas o rails não está deixando mexer no hash, tentei usar a `gem Money`, mas não me pareceu muito útil (Ou não entendi muito bem como usar, ela só dá erro dizendo que o valor não é um número, claro vem string e não estou conseguindo tratar). Talvez eu deveria mudar o tipo de campo no simple form? Mas daí não apareceria a mask.

Alguém sabe como eu poderia exibir a mask e ainda assim salvar o valor tal e qual o usuário digitou no campo (Pensei até em usar como string, mas daria muito trabalho depois para fazer cálculos de registros, soma, média, mediana etc).

Answer (score 0):

Bem depois de algum aperto fiz da seguinte forma (Pode não ser a melhor, mas funcionou):

No meu controller

`@financial = Financial.new(financial_params)
 @financial.value = financial_params[:value].gsub(/[.]/, '').gsub(/[,]/, '.')`

Desta forma antes de salvar recebo a string que veio do form com a mascara e tudo e retiro os pontos e virgulas e ajusto para como o rails conseguirá ler e converter. Em seguida mostro nas views o resultado da seguinte forma:

`<td><%= number_to_currency(financial.value, unit: "R$", separator: ",", delimiter: ".") %></td>`

Agora está funcionando como eu queria.